# Can Javascript DataTables show raw/literal strings instead of interpretting escape characters?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I've built a Flask app that displays text data from CSV files uploaded by the user in a DataTable. Occasionally a text might include escape characters or even a bit of code/tags. I want all text to display **exactly** as it was written in the original file, including any escape characters or other code/tags. For reasons I don't need to get into, solutions involving replacing characters within the text itself will not work for my use case (so an extra backslash or ascii character or something is unacceptable).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Below is some javascript code I had hoped would work using `String.raw`, but it still renders "This is <b>bold</b>" as "This is **bold**". Not what I expected.

simplified code:

```js
var sample = '<i>I</i> &amp; <b>B</b>';

var data_table = $("#data-table").DataTable();

function redraw(sample) {
  data_table.clear();
  data_table.row.add([
    String.raw`${sample}`
  ]);
  data_table.draw();
}
i.value = sample;
i.oninput();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

Test:<input id="i" type="text" oninput="redraw(value)" size="50">

<div class="container">
  <table border id="data-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>default</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a piece of `data['table']` example containing these "escapes" you are referring to? Also, String.raw is not supposed to "strip HTML markup out of strings", it is for (not) processing JavaScript escape sequences in template literals.

Comment: done. and to clarify, I don't want to strip anything out of the strings. What I want is for the tags to be displayed to the user as part of the text instead of interpretted by the browser.

Comment: `String.raw` only does some escaping of certain characters by putting a backslash in front of them, if I am not mistaken? That doesn't help you here, you'd need to apply _HTML encoding_, so that all those special characters like <, > and & get replaced with their named entities.

Comment: Or you handle this, by explicitly specifying how DataTables should render your data - the `text` helper would do exactly what you need, https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Text-helper: _"The `text` helper will ensure that any potentially dangerous HTML in the source data will not be executed by escaping the HTML entities."_

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @CBroe who provided the key to the answer in their comment above.

The solution was to use the `text` render helper [datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Text-helper](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Text-helper)

With this information, I was able to declare how to render specific columns when the DataTable was first defined, and so any rows that are subsequently added will rely on that definition for how to display.

Here's the original and fixed code: in adjacent columns:

```js
var sample = '<i>I</i> &amp; <b>B</b>';

var data_table = $("#data-table").DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [1],
    render: DataTable.render.text()
  }],
});

function redraw(sample) {
  data_table.clear();
  data_table.row.add([sample, sample]);
  data_table.draw();
}

i.value = sample;
i.oninput();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

Test:<input id="i" type="text" oninput="redraw(value)" size="50">

<div class="container">
  <table border id="data-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>default</th>
        <th>text()</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Try at [live.datatables.net](https://live.datatables.net/wakomaxe/1/edit?html,js,output)